# Posterior for parameters of quantified normal distribution?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, posterior

Let $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ be a uni-dimensional normal variable with the parameters $\mu$, $\sigma$.
Given $n$ fixed cut-offs $-\infty < r_0 < \ldots < r_{n-1} < \infty$, I quantify the variable $X$ with the variable $Q$ defined below:
$Q = \begin{cases}
    0,~\text{if $X \leq r_0$} \\
    \ldots \\
    i,~\text{if $r_{i-1} < X \leq r_i$} \\
    \ldots \\
    n,~\text{if $r_{n-1} < X$}
\end{cases}$

Consider we have the sample $q$ drawn from $Q$. Let the prior $p(\mu, \sigma)$ to be just Gaussian. 
I want to get a (possibly approximate) formula for the posterior $p(\mu, \sigma | q)$. E.g. to approximate it with Gaussian $p(\mu, \sigma | q) \sim N(\mu', \sigma')$ with formulas for $\mu'$ and $\sigma'$. Is it possible?

Comment: This looks like a standard interval-censoring problem; the likelihood should be reasonably easy to deal with. What do you mean by "approximate normally" there? Were you after a Gaussian approximation to the posterior?

Comment: Thanks for reference! My goal to have an approximate formula for posterior parameters. In this case I will have no need to do any MCMC simulations, just the exact math. As a proposition I want it to be gaussian.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am unsure of the intended meaning of your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "approximate normally" means in this context. For what it's worth, here is the approach I would take.

Let $\Phi(\,\cdot\,)$ denote the cdf for the standard normal distribution. For $j \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$, define 
\begin{equation}
\pi_j(\mu,\sigma) = \Phi\left(\frac{r_j-\mu}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{r_{j-1}-\mu}{\sigma}\right) ,
\end{equation}
where $r_{-1} = -\infty$ and $r_n = \infty$. Note $\sum_{j=0}^n \pi_j(\mu,\sigma) = 1$. The discrete random variable $q_i$ is categorical. The probability that $q_i = j$ is given by
\begin{equation}
p(q_i = j|\mu,\sigma) = \pi_j(\mu,\sigma) .
\end{equation}
The likelihood for $q_{1:T} = (q_1, \ldots, q_T)$ is
\begin{equation}
p(q_{1:T}|\mu,\sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^T p(q_i|\mu,\sigma) . 
\end{equation}
The posterior distribution is characterized by
\begin{equation}
p(\mu,\sigma|q_{1:T}) \propto p(q_{1:T}|\mu,\sigma)\,p(\mu,\sigma) , 
\end{equation}
where $p(\mu,\sigma)$ is the prior for $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks for your great response! I want the posterior to have a normal distribution. And so my question is how to approximate its mean and variance.